# abstract class errors simple class

Tags: java, class, abstract

```
public abstract class Shape{
    
    protected Point position;
    
    public Shape (Point p)
    {
        this.position=new Point(p);
    }
    
    public abstract int getArea();
    public abstract int gerPerimeter();
    public abstract boolean overlap(Shape other);
    
}
```

```js
public class Rectangle extends Shape
{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    
    public Rectangle(Point position,int width,int height)
    {
        super(position);
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }
    @Override
    public int getArea()
    {
        return width*height;
    }
    @Override
    public int getPerimeter()
    {
        return width*2+height*2;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean overlap(Rectangle other)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

> Rectangle.java:1: error: Rectangle is not abstract and does not override abstract method overlap(Shape) in Shape
>
> public class Rectangle extends Shape
> ^
>
> Rectangle.java:17: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>
> @Override
> ^
>
> Rectangle.java:22: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>
> @Override
> ^
>
> 3 errors

Answer (score 1):

This method  `public boolean overlap(Rectangle other)` and this

`public abstract boolean overlap(Shape other);` are not the same,

even if is true that **Rectangle** extends/implements **Shape**...

so technically you are not overriding all the methods of the abstract class...

and the **Override** annotation giving you a complain since that method can be found in the super class....

Answer (score 0):

`Rectangle`'s `overlap` method must have the same signature as the parent's class method in order to override it :

```
@Override
public boolean overlap(Shape other)
{
    return false;
}
```

If you require that the `Shape` passed to `Rectangle`'s `overlap` be a `Rectangle`, you can check the type using `instanceof` :

```
@Override
public boolean overlap(Shape other)
{
    if (other instanceof Rectangle) {
        Rectangle otherRect = (Rectangle) other;
        ...   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the error message

> Rectangle.java:17: error: method does not override or implement a
>   method from a supertype
>
> @Override

you will notice that your Rectangle class is only sub-classing the shape class which means that something like

```
@Override
public boolean overlap(Rectangle other)
```

would be wrong because java expects that the superclass should have the method `overlap(Rectangle other)`. Instead, it sees `overlap(Shape other)` and they are completely different.
Solution: if you still want the method, then remove the @Override annotation.

For the error message

> Rectangle.java:22: error: method does not override or implement a
>   method from a supertype
>
> @Override

Well you still haven't overridden the method yet which you must. 
Solution: either change the `overlap(Rectangle other)` to `overlap(Shape other)` or completely write a new override method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean overlap(Shape other)
{
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helped.